# Altering a sparql query with a submit field

Tags: javascript, forms, select, sparql, sgvizler

I have a question about my project.
We want to let the user select a value in a select form and then import that value in a sparql Query. We're are not using php or something like that. the value should be in the sparql query.This is what i've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="sgvzlr_script" src="../sgvizler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  sgvizler
      .defaultEndpointURL("http://lod.xdams.org/sparql#")
      .prefix('default','http://cdec.opendams.org/lod/shoah/')
      .prefix('persecution','http://cdec.opendams.org/lod/shoah/persecution/');    

  //// Leave this as is. Ready, steady, go!
  $(document).ready(sgvizler.containerDrawAll);
</script>
```

```
<h1>TEST</h1>

<html>
<body>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<h2>gTable</h2>

<div id="sgvzl_example19" 
 data-sgvizler-query="SELECT *
              WHERE 
              { persecution:'value' ?b ?c
              }
              LIMIT 10"
 data-sgvizler-chart="google.visualization.Table"
 data-sgvizler-log="2"
 style="width:800px; height:600px;"
 ></div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Jelle

Comment: What is the question or issue you are having with what you tried?

Comment: we want to let the user select a value with the select form. And then we want to use that value in the sparql query: 
              SELECT * WHERE 
              { persecution:'value' ?b ?c }

Comment: But it doesnt work in the way we tried above :(